# Vue show/hide error based on result of @change function

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to conditionally render an error message based on the email address a user enters when they register.  If the email is in use, show the error. If the email is not in use, proceed with registration.  What I have so far is after the user clicks out of the text field, an on change event calls a function that returns true if the email is available.

```
<v-flex xs12>
  <v-text-field
    autocomplete="ignoreautocompleteemail"
    :rules="emailRules"
    append-icon="email"
    v-model="person.email"
    outlined
    @change="checkEmail(person.email)"
    name="email address"
    label="Email Address"
    type="text"
  ></v-text-field>
</v-flex>
```

I'm not familiar enough with vue yet to understand how to do something with the result of the @change event.

How can I use the value returned from @change to conditionally render an error message in my text field?

Many thanks in advance,
Chappie Johnson

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.  Ended up putting a property in the data() section of my component that is updated based on the value of the @change event. Then I do something pretty simple with the error-message props.

```
<v-flex xs12>
  <v-text-field
    autocomplete="ignoreautocompleteemail"
    :rules="emailRules"
    :error-messages="!this.emailAvailable ? 'Email unavailable!' : ''"
    append-icon="email"
    v-model="person.email"
    outlined
    @change="checkEmail(person.email)"
    name="email address"
    label="Email Address"
    type="text"
  ></v-text-field>
</v-flex>
```

-

```
data() {
    return {
        emailAvailable: true;
    }
},
methods: {
     checkEmail(person) {
      authService
        .checkEmail(this.person)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.data.email_available === false) {
            this.emailAvailable = false;
          } else {
            this.emailAvailable = true;
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {});
    },
}
```

Not sure if there is a better way to do this, but it solves my problem for now.

Comment: That's an excellent solution and is how you should do it.

There are two things you can do to improve it.  
Since emailAvailable is dependent on email_available, you can simply do `this.emailAvailable=response.data.email_available`

Or, you could use async/await and set the value directly.
`async checkEmail(person) {return await AuthService.checkEmail(this.email)}`
`@change=emailAvaliable=checkEmail(person.email)`

Comment: thanks for the tip and for the vote of confidence! glad to know my skills are transferable to front end work.